# IE margins not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I've got a couple stacked divs.  My css is set to put a 10px margin between the two divs.
In Firefox, everything looks great.
In IE 11, it appears that the margins are replaced with padding inside the div and the margin between the divs is gone.
[image]

Here is my css for the divs:

```
.home_news {
    width:453px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
}
.home_facebook {
    width:453px;
    height: 505px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas for me?

Thanks!

EDIT: added some html

This is how the two divs are set-up:

```
<div class="home_news">
    <div class="block_title">Current News</div>
    <table>Each row has different news item</table>
</div>

<div class="home_facebook">
    <div class="block_title">Follow us on Facebook</div>
    FACEBOOK MODULE GOES HERE
</div>
```

Pretty basic setup.  The data for the news block is pulled from a database.

I pulled the PIE out of the mix and while it did seem to fix the margin between the divs, it also removed the corner radius from the divs.  The padding issue is still present.  You might not be able to see it in the graphic posted, but the grey shading in the title block in the IE divs is pushed down about 10px.

Comment: OK for me - http://jsfiddle.net/n3pRs/

Comment: ditto that [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DqeTu/) seems the culprit might be PIE

Comment: Ok for me as well bud (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/esHud/) How about some HTML?

Comment: The box model is a thing, that's unified in all browsers.

Comment: try a </br> between two main div's

Comment: I just tried a fiddle from the comments in IE and FF and both have same behavior - working good, so looks like to me that you might have another styles in your CSS overriding this.